# Return an expression that is a mutable object in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mutable, symbols, procedure

Hi I am trying to write a function that will return an expression that is mutable and can be used as a procedure.

For example:

`(fooeq 1 2)` would return `(eq? 1 2)`

and

`((fooeq 1 2))` would return `#f`

Is there a way to write an expression that is a symbol that can be converted into a procedure?

EDIT: I got it, thanks for the responses.  In case anyone else was wondering it's the (eval p).

Comment: How would the computer magically know to turn `fooeq` into `eq?`?

Comment: This is just an arbitrary example.  Sorry let me be a little more clear.  I want my original function, lets just call it foo, to actually return an arbitrary value that could then be evaluated like a procedure. So I'm wondering how I could take a value like '(eq 1 2) and actually treat it like a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want `fooeq` to evaluate to a function:

```
> (define (fooeq a b)
    (lambda () (eq? a b)))

> ((fooeq 1 2))
#f
> ((fooeq 1 1))
#t
>
```

A function that takes one or more functions as input or outputs a function is known as a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Comment: +1 I like your answer, because even though it doesn't answer the OP's question, it's a much better thing to want to do than what the OP wants to do with eval. :-P